# Multiple save files?

Tags: alien-isolation

I would like to start a new game without losing the other one. I know that there's no multiple save profile in this game but is there a way to save the file on your computer and load it later on ?

So you could just create new save file and backup them somewhere else in your computer.

Comment: I searched briefly for the save files, and have not found them yet. I will see if I can find this evening.

Answer (score 1):

Necroing this quite hard, but a post on the [Steam Community](https://steamcommunity.com/app/214490/discussions/0/619568192860176247/#c619568192862625856) shows the save location is in the Steam Install directory.

> They're here:
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\userdata[user number]\214490
>
> Just back up this entire folder. The save file itself in the "remote"
>   folder.

Change the "C:\Program FIles (x86)\Steam" to your Steam install directory